# How to delete custom fields from Big Object?

Tags: custom-field, delete, big-object

How do I delete non-indexed custom fields on a Big Object ? I do not see a 'delete' option next to 'edit' option of a field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant delete a field or indexes in Big Object once created, you need to start over with a new Big Object.

I can see a documentation for indexes for this :

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_bo_considerations.htm&type=5

> After you’ve created the index, you can’t edit or delete it. To change the index, you must start over with a new big object.

But not for fields, but I think that will apply to fields too.

Comment: Ok. I think so too. First I thought it might be a profile permission issue. But looks like a delete option is not there